# Assign specific color to each label in scale_fill_brewer

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to assign to each specific label a specific color without using Palettes
for example for "abscent" red and for for "present" blue

```
scale_fill_brewer(
  type = "div",
  name = element_blank(),
  labels = c("abscent", "present"),
  palette = "RdBu",
  guide = guide_legend(
    direction = "horizontal",
    title.position = "top"
  )
)
```

Comment: If you want to set custom colors I would suggest to use `scale_fill_manual`, e.g.  `scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue"), labels = c("abscent","present"))`. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a working ggplot2 code and a snippet of your data or some fake data. It would also help to clarify what's exactly the issue or what's your desired result.